# sem_wait and sem_post are not working as expected, No compilation errors but not getting an expected output

Tags: c, process, fork, semaphore, child-process

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
int process3(int i);
int process2(int i);
int process1(int i);
sem_t sem1;
sem_t sem2;
sem_t sem3;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int pid1,pid2,value,i=0;
sem_init(&sem1, 1, 0);
sem_init(&sem2, 1, 1);
sem_init(&sem3, 1, 0);
value=atoi(argv[1]);        
pid1=fork();    
if(pid1==0)
{
pid2=fork();
}
while(i<=value)
{
if(pid2==0)
{
sem_wait(&sem2);
process3(i);
sem_post(&sem1);
}
if(pid1==0&&pid2>0)
{
sem_wait(&sem3);
process2(i);
sem_post(&sem2);
}
if(pid1>0)
{
sem_wait(&sem1);
process1(i);
sem_post(&sem3);
}
i++;        
}
return 0;
}
int process3(int i)
{
if(i%3==0)
{
printf("%d\n",i);
}
} 
int process2(int i)
{
if((i+1)%3==0)
{
printf("%d\n",i);
}
}
int process1(int i)
{ 
if((i+2)%3==0)
{
 printf("%d\n",i);
}
}
```

Expected error is: 0,1,2,3,....maxnum given along with output command.
Got output:
0
The aim of my code is to create two child processes and to print numbers in an increasing order. But getting an unexpected output as shown above.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: For pity's sake, please learn how to indent code in SO.  Prepare the material properly formatted — suggested indent level of 4 spaces; spaces are mandatory, but 4 isn't — and copy it into the edit box.  Make sure that looks like it should (ignore the preview).  Then select the code (or code fragment) and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the code by 4 spaces.  Now look at the preview window.  If you didn't have any tabs in the code, it should look correct.

Comment: You aren't doing any error checking of any of the functions directly — somewhat indirectly, you sort of check `fork()`.  You don't know what's going wrong.  The first step is to make sure that every system call that can fail is checked for an error indication, and print the appropriate error message (and probably exit).  There are few system calls that can't fail — `getpid()` is one such, and the others are similar.  Another debugging step is to print (copious) debugging information, with most lines prefixed with the process's PID.  Done reasonably, that'll tell you more about what's going on.

Comment: Finally, from me, for now, you should note that `i` is not in shared memory, so any changes made by one of the processes to its copy of `i` does not affect the value of `i` in any of the other processes.  Similarly, I'm not sure whether the semaphores are shared across processes.  They're created in the original (parent) process, but I think the copies in the children become independent and changes made by one process are not reflected in other processes.  I might be wrong on that — check the manual.  With `i`, I'm confident; with `semN`, I'm just lazy.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts. 3) separate functions be 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Several of the functions have a signature indicating that the function returns an `int` but the body of the function(s) do not return anything.  Note: do not access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameter actually exists.

Comment: the function: `fork()` 1) can fail 2) has three kinds of returned values <0 means error, ==0 means child process, >0 means parent process  For each call to `fork()` all three conditions need to be checked

Comment: the function: `atoi()` does not return any error condition when it fails. Suggest using `strtol()` or similar function, which does return any error indication

Comment: you state: `NO COMPILATION ERRORS`,  That is not strictly true,  Suggest enabling the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: when `pid1` is 0, then in the child process,  The child process execution must not fall through into the parent code.  I.E. always keep execution paths completely separate.

Comment: at this statement: `while(i<=value)` in parent and child1 and child2 and parent knows nothing about the value in `pid2` so this statement, in the parent, is testing uninitialized values, `if(pid1==0&&pid2>0)`  There are other problems in the posted code, but the main problem is not keeping the execution paths separate.  Note: the calls to `print()` in the `process#()` functions all output the same line of text, so there is no easy way to determine which process produced each line

Comment: The posted code is using semaphores.  For the current code logic, a mutex would be much better